# Two-body pulley system

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum

Suppose I put a rope over a pulley. I attach one end to an object with the same mass as me and I hold onto the other end. If I try to climb the rope, my position with respect to the ground will not change, while the object on the other end will begin moving upwards. How can I prove that I will not move relative to the ground?